# How to use buttons in html to keep language the user chooses in php session

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have multiple PHP files and need to use `session_start()` to keep track of the website language. There are two buttons **ENG** and **GRE** the default language assigned to `$_SESSION['lang']` is **ENG**. When the user clicks on **Greek** the `$_SESSION['lang']` needs to be updated and all the databases contents that are in Greek need to be displayed.

functions.php

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
session_start();

function getLang(){
    if (isset($_GET['lang'])){
        return $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    }
    else{
        return $lang='ENG';
    }
}

function getValue($name,$connection){
    $lang = getLang();
    $query = "SELECT Text FROM users WHERE Nickname='$name' AND Lang='$lang'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return checkText($text['Text'],$name,$connection);
}

function  checkText($text,$name,$connection){
    if ($text==null){
        $sql = "SELECT Text FROM users WHERE Nickname='$name' AND Lang='Eng'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        $text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $text['Text'];
    }
    else{
        return $text;
    }
}

function getPk($name,$connection){
    $lang = getLang();
    $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE Nickname='$name' AND Lang='$lang'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $text['id'];
}
```

index.php

```
<?php include "functions.php";
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'ENG';
?>
```

This is were I start the session.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.lang').on('click',function(){
            var lang = $(this).attr('id');
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    var pks = [];
    var nicks = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bt').on('click',function(){
            $('.to_edit').each(function(){
                var a = $(this).attr('data-pk');
                var nick = $(this).attr('data-name');
                $(this).wrapInner("<a class='edit1'></a>");
                $('.edit1').attr('data-type','text');
                pks.push(a);
                nicks.push(nick);
            });
            var i=0;
            $('.edit1').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('data-pk', pks[i]);
                $(this).attr('data-name',nicks[i]);
                i++;
            });

            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode='inline';
            var options = {};
            options.url = 'update.php';
            $('.edit1').editable(options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first script is what I've written so far for the buttons that have the ENG and GRE writings and the second is inline editing with x-editable.

Here are the buttons:

```
<button class="lang" id="En"><a href="?lang=ENG">ENG</a></button>
<button class="lang" id="Gr"><a href="?lang=GRE">GRE</a></button>
```

My questions are how to obtain the id of the buttons which is **ENG** and **GRE**, how to update `$_SESSION[lang']`, will I need to use **session_start()** in all files?

Comment: You should show examples of your code thus far, SO is designed to help with specific problems that people are having. There are too many different scenarios for what you are looking to do, we need to know how you want to do it first.

Comment: provide only necessary code

Comment: sorry guys still getting used to stack overflow will do!

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start()` right at the beginning of `connection.php` or `functions.php` as some of them you should always include in every file you have.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username =  "root";
    ..
```

In the same file you have included in every other file, add the condition if the language has changed:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) { $_SESSION['lang'] = 'ENG'; }
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```